# WebView Issue when using thumbnail page

Tags: android, webview

Some time page with poster thumbnail throws null pointer exception in web view[Andoid].

I have already tried this code.

```
`lateinit var webView: WebView
webView = view.findViewById(R.id.webView) as WebView
 webView.settings.javaScriptEnabled = true
        webView.isHorizontalScrollBarEnabled = false
        webView.postDelayed({ webView.loadUrl(url) }, 100)
          webView.webViewClient = object : WebViewClient() {
            override fun onPageStarted(view: WebView?, url: String?, favicon: Bitmap?) {
                super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon)
                progressLayout.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            }
            override fun onPageFinished(view: WebView, url: String) {
                // do your stuff here
                progressLayout.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
                homeScreenImage.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }`
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try this if it works
you can use web chrome client and override default video poster and load default bitmap in case of loading fails

```
  webView.webChromeClient = object : WebChromeClient() {
            override fun getDefaultVideoPoster(): Bitmap? {
                val result = super.getDefaultVideoPoster()
                return result ?: Bitmap.createBitmap(1, 1, Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            }

            override fun onProgressChanged(view: WebView?, newProgress: Int) {
                super.onProgressChanged(view, newProgress)
            }

        }
```